# " Threading Error" Couldn't run the shell after converting single client shell into multi client shell by adding "threads"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets, websocket

"This code runs but won't be able to do anything,when I run this code what I am expecting is that I am going to get my shell but I get nothing it all worked fine before threading but when i edited this to convert it into multi_client then it all happened"

```
import socket
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time

NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2
JOB_NUMBER = [1,2]
queue = Queue()
all_connections = []
all_addresses = []

def socket_create():
try:

    global host
    global port
    global s
    host = ''
    port = 9999
    s = socket.socket()
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Socket creation error: " + str(msg))



def socket_bind():

try:
    global host
    global port
    global  s
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Socket binding error: " + str(msg))
    time.sleep(5)
    socket_bind()


def accept_connections():
for c in all_connections:
    c.close()
del all_connections[:]
del all_addresses[:]
while 1:
    try:
        conn, address = s.accept()
        conn.setblocking(1)
        all_connections.append(conn)
        all_addresses.append(address)
        print("\nConnection has been established: " + address[0])
    except:
         print("Errorr accepting connections")


def start_turtle():
while True:
    cmd = input('turtle> ')
    if cmd == 'list':
        list_connections()
    elif 'select' in cmd:
        conn = get_target(cmd)
        if conn is not None:
            send_target_commands(conn)

    else:
        print("Command not Recognized")



def list_connections():
results = ''
for i, conn in enumerate(all_connections):
    try:
        conn.send(str.encode(' '))
        conn.recv(20480)
    except:
        del all_connections[i]
        del all_addresses[i]
        continue
    results += str(i) + '   ' + str(all_addresses[i][0]) + '   ' + str(all_addresses[i][1]) + '\n'
    print('------ Clients -----' + '\n' + results)


def get_target(cmd):
try:
    target = cmd.replace('select ', '')
    target = int(target)
    conn = all_connections[target]
    print("You are now connected to " + str(all_addresses[target][0]))
    print(str(all_addresses[target][0]) + "> ", end = "")
    return conn
except:
    print("Now a valid selection")
    return None


def send_target_commands(conn):
while True:
    try:
        cmd = input()
        if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
            conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
            client_response = str(conn.recv(20480), "utf-8")
            print(client_response, end="")
        if cmd == 'quit':
            break
    except:
        print("Connection was lost")
        break


def create_workers():
for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
    t = threading.Thread(target=work)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

def work():
while True:
    x = queue.get()
    if x == 1:
        socket_create()
        socket_bind()
        accept_connections()
    if x == 2:
        start_turtle()
        queue.task_done()
def create_jobs():
for x in JOB_NUMBER:
    queue.put(x)
    queue.join()

create_workers()
create_jobs()
```

Comment: You don't appear to be waiting for the threads to complete.

Comment: how i can complete the threads?

Comment: Your call to `queue.join()` will block until your socket stops accepting connections, and the 2nd job won't be started until then.

Comment: is there anyway to get rid from this?

Comment: Well, why not just remove the `queue.join()`?

Comment: I removed that and tried,the program automatically stop itself when I started the program